# Outlook to excel VBA stops searching body after first match

Tags: excel, vba, email, outlook, extract

I wrote a code to pull data from outlook to excel, And its 80% working :) It does pull info but not from the whole email.

I receive emails in the same format with pricing and other info on them. These are for purchase orders what have more than 1 line usually. They are in this format:

Item Number             : 00001

Vendor Sales Order Number :

Vendor Material Number  :

SAP Material Number     :

Vendor Description      :

SAP Description         :

Vendor Quantity         : 30.000 EA

SAP Quantity            : 30.000 EA

Quantity UOM            : EA

Vendor Delivery Date    : 20.09.2014

SAP Delivery Date       : 20.09.2014

Action Request          :

Following details does not match for PO line item 00001

Vendor Price            : USD 0.00 for 1 EA

SAP Price               : USD 0.01 for 1 EA

Item Number             : 00002

Vendor Sales Order Number :

Vendor Material Number  :

SAP Material Number     :

Vendor Description      :

SAP Description         :

Vendor Quantity         : 70.000 EA

SAP Quantity            : 70.000 EA

Quantity UOM            : EA

Vendor Price            : USD 3.90 for 1 EA

SAP Price               : USD 3.90 for 1 EA

Vendor Delivery Date    : 20.09.2014

SAP Delivery Date       : 20.09.2014

Action Request          :

Quantity and Requested Date all matched with PO. Item 00002

As you can see from the code i am pulling multiple things from these emails that have the same beginning string. After it pulls line 1, the code moves to the next email without searching the entire body of the email for further matches. How can i fix this? Stuck :)

```
Option Explicit

Sub CopyToExcel()
Dim xlApp As Object
Dim xlWB As Object
Dim xlSheet As Object
Dim olItem As Outlook.MailItem
Dim vText As Variant
Dim sText As String
Dim vItem As Variant
Dim i As Long
Dim rCount As Long
Dim bXStarted As Boolean
Const strPath As String = "Excel filepath here" 'the path of the     workbook

If Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection.Count = 0 Then
MsgBox "No Items selected!", vbCritical, "Error"
Exit Sub
End If
On Error Resume Next
Set xlApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
If Err <> 0 Then
Application.StatusBar = "Please wait while Excel source is opened ... "
Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
bXStarted = True
End If
On Error GoTo 0
'Open the workbook to input the data
Set xlWB = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(strPath)
Set xlSheet = xlWB.Sheets("Sheet1")

'Process each selected record
 For Each olItem In Application.ActiveWindow.Selection
sText = olItem.Body
vText = Split(sText, Chr(13))
'Find the next empty line of the worksheet
 rCount = xlSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1

'Check each line of text in the message body
For i = UBound(vText) To 0 Step -1
  rCount = rCount
  If InStr(1, vText(i), "Purchase Order          :") > 0 Then
        vItem = Split(vText(i), Chr(58))
        xlSheet.Range("A" & rCount) = Trim(vItem(1))
    End If

    If InStr(1, vText(i), "Vendor                  :") > 0 Then
        vItem = Split(vText(i), Chr(58))
        xlSheet.Range("B" & rCount) = Trim(vItem(1))
    End If

    If InStr(1, vText(i), "Item Number             :") > 0 Then
        vItem = Split(vText(i), Chr(58))
        xlSheet.Range("C" & rCount) = Trim(vItem(1))
    End If

    If InStr(1, vText(i), "Vendor Quantity         :") > 0 Then
        vItem = Split(vText(i), Chr(58))
        xlSheet.Range("D" & rCount) = Trim(vItem(1))
    End If

    If InStr(1, vText(i), "SAP Quantity            :") > 0 Then
        vItem = Split(vText(i), Chr(58))
        xlSheet.Range("E" & rCount) = Trim(vItem(1))
    End If

    If InStr(1, vText(i), "Quantity UOM            :") > 0 Then
        vItem = Split(vText(i), Chr(58))
        xlSheet.Range("F" & rCount) = Trim(vItem(1))
    End If

    If InStr(1, vText(i), "Vendor Price            :") > 0 Then
        vItem = Split(vText(i), Chr(58))
        xlSheet.Range("G" & rCount) = Trim(vItem(1))
    End If

    If InStr(1, vText(i), "SAP Price               :") > 0 Then
        vItem = Split(vText(i), Chr(58))
        xlSheet.Range("H" & rCount) = Trim(vItem(1))
    End If

    If InStr(1, vText(i), "Vendor Delivery Date    :") > 0 Then
        vItem = Split(vText(i), Chr(58))
        xlSheet.Range("I" & rCount) = Trim(vItem(1))
    End If

    If InStr(1, vText(i), "SAP Delivery Date       :") > 0 Then
        vItem = Split(vText(i), Chr(58))
        xlSheet.Range("J" & rCount) = Trim(vItem(1))
    End If

    If InStr(1, vText(i), "Text here:") > 0 Then
        vItem = Split(vText(i), Chr(58))
        xlSheet.Range("K" & rCount) = Trim(vItem(1))
    End If

    If InStr(1, vText(i), "Text here:") > 0 Then
        vItem = Split(vText(i), Chr(58))
        xlSheet.Range("L" & rCount) = Trim(vItem(1))
    End If

    If InStr(1, vText(i), "Text here:") > 0 Then
        vItem = Split(vText(i), Chr(58))
        xlSheet.Range("M" & rCount) = Trim(vItem(1))
    End If

    If InStr(1, vText(i), "Text here") > 0 Then
        vItem = Split(vText(i), Chr(58))
        xlSheet.Range("N" & rCount) = Trim(vItem(1))
    End If

    If InStr(1, vText(i), "Text here") > 0 Then
        vItem = Split(vText(i), Chr(58))
        xlSheet.Range("O" & rCount) = Trim(vItem(1))
    End If

    If InStr(1, vText(i), "Text here") > 0 Then
        vItem = Split(vText(i), Chr(58))
        xlSheet.Range("P" & rCount) = Trim(vItem(1))
    End If

    If InStr(1, vText(i), "Text here") > 0 Then
        vItem = Split(vText(i), Chr(58))
        xlSheet.Range("Q" & rCount) = Trim(vItem(1))
    End If
Next i
xlWB.Save
Next olItem
xlWB.Close SaveChanges:=True
If bXStarted Then
End If
Set xlApp = Nothing
Set xlWB = Nothing
Set xlSheet = Nothing
Set olItem = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Are you sure it's only pulling the first one or is it the last one?

Comment: Its pulling the line item 1, then not searching the rest of the email for other possible matches to the string. Some of these have 10+ line items, and this only exports line 1 to excel

Answer (score 0):

## Code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub CopyToExcel()
Dim xlApp As Object
Dim xlWB As Object
Dim xlSheet As Object
Dim olItem As Object
Dim vText As Variant
Dim sText As String
Dim vItem As Variant
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim rCount As Long
Dim bXStarted As Boolean
Const strPath As String = "Excel filepath here" 'the path of the     workbook

If Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection.Count = 0 Then
MsgBox "No Items selected!", vbCritical, "Error"
Exit Sub
End If
On Error Resume Next
Set xlApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
If Err <> 0 Then
Application.StatusBar = "Please wait while Excel source is opened ... "
Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
bXStarted = True
End If
On Error GoTo 0
'Open the workbook to input the data
Set xlWB = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(strPath)
Set xlSheet = xlWB.Sheets("Sheet1")

'Process each selected record
 For j = 1 To Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection.Count
 Set olItem = Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection.Item(j)
 
 If olItem.Class = 43 Then
sText = olItem.Body
vText = Split(sText, Chr(13))
'Find the next empty line of the worksheet
 rCount = xlSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1

'Check each line of text in the message body
For i = UBound(vText) To 0 Step -1
  If InStr(1, vText(i), "Purchase Order          :") > 0 Then
        vItem = Split(vText(i), Chr(58))
        xlSheet.Range("A" & rCount) = Trim(vItem(1))
    End If

    If InStr(1, vText(i), "Vendor                  :") > 0 Then
        vItem = Split(vText(i), Chr(58))
        xlSheet.Range("B" & rCount) = Trim(vItem(1))
    End If

    If InStr(1, vText(i), "Item Number             :") > 0 Then
        vItem = Split(vText(i), Chr(58))
        xlSheet.Range("C" & rCount) = Trim(vItem(1))
    End If

    If InStr(1, vText(i), "Vendor Quantity         :") > 0 Then
        vItem = Split(vText(i), Chr(58))
        xlSheet.Range("D" & rCount) = Trim(vItem(1))
    End If

    If InStr(1, vText(i), "SAP Quantity            :") > 0 Then
        vItem = Split(vText(i), Chr(58))
        xlSheet.Range("E" & rCount) = Trim(vItem(1))
    End If

    If InStr(1, vText(i), "Quantity UOM            :") > 0 Then
        vItem = Split(vText(i), Chr(58))
        xlSheet.Range("F" & rCount) = Trim(vItem(1))
    End If

    If InStr(1, vText(i), "Vendor Price            :") > 0 Then
        vItem = Split(vText(i), Chr(58))
        xlSheet.Range("G" & rCount) = Trim(vItem(1))
    End If

    If InStr(1, vText(i), "SAP Price               :") > 0 Then
        vItem = Split(vText(i), Chr(58))
        xlSheet.Range("H" & rCount) = Trim(vItem(1))
    End If

    If InStr(1, vText(i), "Vendor Delivery Date    :") > 0 Then
        vItem = Split(vText(i), Chr(58))
        xlSheet.Range("I" & rCount) = Trim(vItem(1))
    End If

    If InStr(1, vText(i), "SAP Delivery Date       :") > 0 Then
        vItem = Split(vText(i), Chr(58))
        xlSheet.Range("J" & rCount) = Trim(vItem(1))
    End If

    If InStr(1, vText(i), "Text here:") > 0 Then
        vItem = Split(vText(i), Chr(58))
        xlSheet.Range("K" & rCount) = Trim(vItem(1))
    End If

    If InStr(1, vText(i), "Text here:") > 0 Then
        vItem = Split(vText(i), Chr(58))
        xlSheet.Range("L" & rCount) = Trim(vItem(1))
    End If

    If InStr(1, vText(i), "Text here:") > 0 Then
        vItem = Split(vText(i), Chr(58))
        xlSheet.Range("M" & rCount) = Trim(vItem(1))
    End If

    If InStr(1, vText(i), "Text here") > 0 Then
        vItem = Split(vText(i), Chr(58))
        xlSheet.Range("N" & rCount) = Trim(vItem(1))
    End If

    If InStr(1, vText(i), "Text here") > 0 Then
        vItem = Split(vText(i), Chr(58))
        xlSheet.Range("O" & rCount) = Trim(vItem(1))
    End If

    If InStr(1, vText(i), "Text here") > 0 Then
        vItem = Split(vText(i), Chr(58))
        xlSheet.Range("P" & rCount) = Trim(vItem(1))
    End If

    If InStr(1, vText(i), "Text here") > 0 Then
        vItem = Split(vText(i), Chr(58))
        xlSheet.Range("Q" & rCount) = Trim(vItem(1))
    End If
Next i
xlWB.Save
rCount = rCount + 1

End If
Next j
xlWB.Close SaveChanges:=True
If bXStarted Then
End If
Set xlApp = Nothing
Set xlWB = Nothing
Set xlSheet = Nothing
Set olItem = Nothing
End Sub
```

This should work.  For some reason Outlook will simply stop execution without error if it encounters a non-mail item in your selection.

Copy and Paste the whole thing (even the `Dim` statements).

Comment: its trying to write it all to the first row still, i can watch it flash super fast overwriting its self @jbaker2160

Comment: I created a test version of this and it worked fine for me.  The only other thing I would suggest is to move `rCount = xlSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1` to directly under `Set xlSheet = xlWB.Sheets("Sheet1")`.  It's rare that this could cause the problem, but it can happen.

Comment: Let me try that now @jbarker2160

Comment: Its putting them all in Row 2, and over writing its self still. With the spreadsheet open on my 2nd monitor i can watch them flash super fast. I wish i knew a bit more about vba. @jbarker2160 I am in excel/office 2010

Comment: Just thought of something, what references have to be checked for this to work? @jbarker2160

Comment: From Outlook you'll just need the Microsoft Excel Object Model.

Comment: i dont know why this wont work for me. Anything you can suggest ?